# REST call to SharePoint Online from Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I have been trying to get user manager using REST call from SharePoint Designer

[https://site_url/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=%27i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7COmi%40company.com%27][1]

above link works ok and returns entire JSON with unwanted properties of that user

I tried below link for getting only manger, so I added **propertyName='Manager'**
but it returns **The parameter name propertyName is not valid**

https://site_url/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v=%27i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7COmi%40company.com%27

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using "GetPropertiesFor" use "GetUserProfilePropertyFor".

Use following url:

```
https://site_url/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v=%27i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7COmi%40company.com%27
```